# add a widget to a LWC Datatable that calls javascript from a menu

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, lightning-datatable

I can't find how this is implemented:

[image]

I'm using a lightning-datatable and would like to convert my current button-icon to what the triangle/square icon above. when clicked it would show two options: edit and delete that would need to call a js function.
I want to replace this guy (utility-edit) pencil which calls an edit handlerowaction method currently. I'm looking to have two options available in a dropdown to call edit and delete handlers with the triangle in a box option.

[image]

js columns:

```
const SAColumns = [
    {
        type: 'button-icon',
        fixedWidth: 40,
        typeAttributes: {
            iconName: 'utility:edit',
            name: 'edit',
            title: 'Edit',
            variant: 'bare',
            alternativeText: 'edit',
            disabled: false
        }
    },
    {label: 'Title', fieldName: 'Title__c', type: 'pickList'},
    {label: 'User', fieldName: 'UserName', Id: 'User__c',type: 'text'}
];
```

html datatable:

```
        <template if:true={hasSAs}>
            <lightning-datatable
                    data={datatableSAs}
                    columns={SAColumns}
                    key-field="Id"
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                    hide-checkbox-column="true"
                    sorted-by={sortBy}
                    sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                    onsort={handleSortdata}
            >
            </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the documentation, but basically you use the type of "actions", and specify a `typeAttributes` called `rowActions`. You can specify a name, label, and icon (and more).

Comment: I guess my question is, where do I find this in the documentation? Does this icon have a name so I can search for it? I had found this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-menu/example
but it's not being implemented the same way I'm trying to do it.

Comment: @SkipVV Look at the [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) documentation. It shows how to use the actions column.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example - yeah just found it. I'll update the solution when I figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: wow. Almost too easy.

Just made these changes:

const actions = [
    { label: 'Edit', name: 'edit' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' },
];

const staffingAssignmentColumns = [
    {label: 'Title', fieldName: 'Title__c', type: 'pickList'},
    {label: 'User', fieldName: 'UserName', Id: 'User__c', type: 'text'},
    {
        type: 'action',
        typeAttributes: {
            rowActions: actions,
            disabled: false
        },
    },

];

and accounted for the edit/delete events in handleRowAction function.

Thanks again